# Turning filled out combo box into a number?

Tags: combobox, ms-access-2013

I have 4 combo boxes where you can select an employee. I want to get a value between 0 and 4 to show how many combo boxes have employees in them. I'll be using this number to automatically calculate length of job times. I think I'm all wrong in my approach.  I think I need to use str or val.

I'm starting with:

```vb
Private Sub ATeamLeaderMon_Change()

If ATeamLeaderMon Is Null Then Me.AMaidMonTotal = Me.AMaidMonTotal + 0
If AMaidMonTotal Is Not Null Then Me.AMaidMonTotal = Me.AMaidMonTotal + 1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
Me!AMaidMonTotal.Value = Abs(Not IsNull(Me!Combo1.Value)) + Abs(Not IsNull(Me!Combo2.Value)) + Abs(Not IsNull(Me!Combo3.Value)) + Abs(Not IsNull(Me!Combo4.Value))
```

Comment: Thank you. I had to add this code in for the change with all 4 combo boxes. It worked great. However, when the text is deleted from the 1st combo box the value will not decrease by 1.  But it does it correctly for combo boxes 2,3 & 4. So when all boxes are empty it still says value of 1.

Comment: That's probably because is doesn't update. That happens when focus is lost.

Comment: Changed from "on change" to "after update" fixed problem.  Works beautifully.